# Django: TruncDate datetime retunrs always datetime

Tags: django, datetime, annotate

I'm using Django 3.2.12 and mysql 8.0.27 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL) and have this models

```
class Anomalie(models.Model):
        dateajout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

I am trying to get all Anomalie per day so I'm using this:

```
items = Anomalie.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('dateajout')).values('dateajout').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('dateajout', 'count')
```

but I get this when I print items:

<QuerySet [{'dateajout': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 1, 58, 15, 509978, tzinfo=), 'count': 1}, {'dateajout': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 10, 12, 56, 9, 682396, tzinfo=), 'count': 1}, {'dateajout': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 11, 12, 23, 54, 838830, tzinfo=), 'count': 1}, {'dateajout': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 12, 13, 5, 38, 557618, tzinfo=), 'count': 1}, {'dateajout': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 6, 3, 57, 31, 69749, tzinfo=), 'count': 1}, {'dateajout': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 6, 14, 15, 38, 704047, tzinfo=), 'count': 1}]>

As you can see, I always get "'count': 1", even if 2 anomalies were created on same day (2023, 8, 6)... I think it's because TruncDate returns a datetime instead of a date...

I searched on many forums like https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/problem-with-count-and-truncdate/10122 or [Formatting dates for annotating count in Django + Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687170/formatting-dates-for-annotating-count-in-django-python-3) but I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `dateajout`, that is still the `datetime`, you use `date`, the thing you annotated:

```
items = (
    Anomalie.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('dateajout'))
    .values('date')
    .annotate(count=Count('id'))
    .values('date', 'count')
)
```

You can simplify this to:

```
items = Anomalie.objects.values(date=TruncDate('dateajout')).annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).order_by('date')
```

Comment: With your code, i get "<QuerySet [{'date': None, 'count': 6}]>"

Comment: @al78310: do you use mysql by any chance?

Comment: yes, I use mysql 8.0.27

Comment: @al78310: likely the timezones are not installed in the database: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/can-not-extract-filter-a-date-time-field-when-time-zones-are-enabled.html

Comment: Yes it was a problem of timezones, for people who will face this issue: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation , thanks a lot